# What is the keyword repeating used for in Swift?

Tags: swift, func

I am reading the official "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)" book and in the part Swift Tour/Generics I encounter the following code

```
func makeArray1<Item>(repeating item: Item, numberOfTimes: Int) -> [Item] {
    var result = [Item]()
    for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes {
        result.append(item)
    }
    return result
}


let arr1 = makeArray1(repeating: "knock", numberOfTimes: 4)
print(arr1)
```

which prints out
**`["knock", "knock", "knock", "knock"]`**

I am confused with the role of the word 'repeating' in the definition of the function makeArray1. I tried to run the code without that word with the following code

```
func makeArray2<Item>(item: Item, numberOfTimes: Int) -> [Item] {
    var result = [Item]()
    for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes {
        result.append(item)
    }
    return result
}


let arr2 = makeArray2(item:"knock", numberOfTimes:4)
print (arr2)
```

and the code gave the same result as before.

**`["knock", "knock", "knock", "knock"]`**

So what is the use of 'repeating' in the code?

Comment: None. But If you write `func method(forSomeParam: ParamType)`, to read the value in your method implementation, you'll access it with `forSomeParam`. But if you want to access it with `param`, you'll need to declare it as such: `func method(forSomeParam param: ParamType)` The doc: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a keyword, it's an optional function argument label that can differ from the local parameter name that's used inside the function/method.

Read the section [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) in The Swift Programming Language:

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each argument is written in the function call with its argument label before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their argument label. …
>
> You write an argument label before the parameter name, separated by a space …
>
> If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that parameter.